# Gspread multiple range update

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

I want to update multiple columns in one call. I know its possible with:

```
# Select a range
cell_list = worksheet.range('C1:C7')

for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = 'O_o'

# Update in batch
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

But I want to update few columns, so range would be 'C1:C7;'E1:E7';'K1:K7'
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

```
range1 = work_sheet.range('C1:C7')
range1.extend(work_sheet.range('E1:E7'))
range1.extend(work_sheet.range('K1:K7'))

for cell in range1:
        cell.value = 'O_o'

# Update in batch
worksheet.update_cells(range1)
```